# javascript/jquery to replace text conditionally with random text from an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, each

I would like to replace a string with a random string from an array if that string equals a certain condition.

So far I have this (which doesn't address the condition part).

the html:

```
<div>
   <span class ="test">foo</span>
</div>
<div>
   <span class ="test">bar</span>
</div>
<div>
   <span class ="test">test</span>
</div>
<div>
   <span class ="test">random</span>
</div>
```

the code:

```
$(".test").each(function () {
var quotes = new Array("foo", "bar", "baz", "chuck"),
    randno = quotes[Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length)];

    $('.test').text(randno);
});
```

This sets every ".test" class the same thing. I get:

foo 
foo
foo
foo

or

bar
bar
bar
bar

---

1. How do I make this only replace the string if it equals say "foo"?
2. If I have multiple "foos" How do i get each "foo" it replaces to be random not all set to the same thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach is to shuffle the replacements array, than use it:

```js
/* Famous shuffle function */
Array.prototype.shuffle = function() {
    for (var j, x, i = this.length; i; j = Math.floor(Math.random() * i), x = this[--i], this[i] = this[j], this[j] = x);
    return this;
};

$.fn.extend({
    randomReplace: function(text, replacements) {
        replacements.shuffle();
        return this.each(function () {
            if( $(this).text().toLowerCase()==text.toLowerCase() )
                $(this).text(replacements.pop());
        });
    }
});

$('.test').randomReplace('foo', ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six']);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="test">foo</span>
<span class="test">bar</span>
<span class="test">foo</span>
<span class="test">foo</span>
<span class="test">bar</span>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `this` in the [`.each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/) callback method

```
$(".test").each(function() {
    var quotes = new Array("foo", "bar", "baz", "chuck"),
        randno = quotes[Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length)];

    //Check condition
    if ($(this).text() === "foo") {
        $(this).text(randno);
    }
});
```

Alternatively you can also use [`.text(function)`](http://api.jquery.com/text/#text-function)

```
var quotes = new Array("foo", "bar", "baz", "chuck");
$(".test").text(function(_, text) {
    var randno = quotes[Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length)];

    //Check condition
    if (text === "foo") {
        return randno;
    }
    return text;
});
```

```js
$(function() {
  var quotes = new Array("foo", "bar", "baz", "chuck");
  $(".test").text(function(_, text) {
    var randno = quotes[Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length)];

    //Check condition
    if (text === "foo") {
      return randno;
    }
    return text;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <span class="test">foo</span>
</div>
<div>
  <span class="test">bar</span>
</div>
<div>
  <span class="test">test</span>
</div>
<div>
  <span class="test">random</span>
</div>
```